# Edit collectionView Cells in UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am creating an app programitcally (on my first try). I have managed to create a collection view and on the click of the add button in the navigation bar a new cell appears. I want to be able to set all cells created to be editable (in other words show the delete button on the cells) when the edit button in the navigation bar is clicked. Currently no matter what I try whether I click on edit or not, nothing happens. I have tried hiding the UIImage of the button as well as the button by calling a function created in the cell class when the edit button is clicked and have also tried moving this function to the ViewController Class, app runs but code doesn't do what it is supposed to.

My Code:

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    
    
    // decelrations of variables for use
    let cell = ListCell()
    let cellId = "cellId"
    var numberOfLists = 0
    var lists = [String]()
    let secondVC = TableViewController()


    
    // for learning purposes: codes sets up the view programitcally along with what is in scenedelagate
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setCollectionView()
    
    }
    
    
    //Function that will generate the collectionView
    func setCollectionView() {
        
        collectionView.register(ListCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        navigationItem.title = "Lists"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(white: 200/255, alpha: 1)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)]
       navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
        
        collectionView.delegate = self //runs the delegate flow methods
        collectionView.dataSource  = self
        
       
             
    }
    
    // to do with enabling editing in CV - function tied to edit button
    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool){

        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
        
        if editing {
            print ("Editing Mode Enabled")
            //cell.showButton()
        } else {
            print ("Editing Mode Closed")
        }
        
        // reloads the view after code is performed
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    
        
     }
    
    
    // func when buttons are tapped to add a collection view
    @objc func addTapped() {
        
        print("This button should not crash")
        numberOfLists += 1
        navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
        collectionView.reloadData()
        
    }
 
    
    
}


// the following block of code has to do with the set up of the collectionView
extension CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    // this code should speficiy how many cells you are going to have in your collectionview
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return numberOfLists
        
    }
    
    // this code lets you reuse a cell
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)-> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ListCell
        
         cell.deleteButton.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "delete"), for: .normal)
        
        return cell
        
    }
    
    // this code sets the sizing of the cells
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        return CGSize(width: (view.frame.width / 2) - 16, height: 100)
        
    }
    
    
    // where to place the cell on the screen
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 9, bottom: 8, right: 8)
        
    }
    
    // this function just checks to see if the cell is selected
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)

        
    }
    
}


//this class sets up the collectionViewCell
class ListCell: UICollectionViewCell {
   
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupCell()

    }
    
    
    fileprivate func setupCell(){
        
        let colors = cellRandomBackgroundColors()
        self.backgroundColor = colors[0]
        self.addSubview(listNameLabel)
        roundCorner()
        setCellShadow()
        
        self.addSubview(deleteButton)
        deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteCell), for: .touchUpInside)
    
        


    }
    

    @objc func deleteCell() {
        
        print ("this button works")
        
        
    }
    
    func showButton() {
        
        
        deleteButton.isHidden = true
        print ("this is supposed to work")
        
        
        
        
    }

    
    func roundCorner() {
        self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0
            self.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            self.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            self.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    }
    
    func setCellShadow() {
         self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
         self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
         self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
         self.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
         self.layer.masksToBounds = false
         self.layer.cornerRadius = 3
         self.clipsToBounds = false
     }
    
    func cellRandomBackgroundColors() -> [UIColor] {
        //Colors
        let red = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.9654200673, green: 0.1590853035, blue: 0.2688751221, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.7559037805, green: 0.1139892414, blue: 0.1577021778, alpha: 1)]
        let orangeRed = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.9338900447, green: 0.4315618277, blue: 0.2564975619, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.8518816233, green: 0.1738803983, blue: 0.01849062555, alpha: 1)]
        let orange = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.9953531623, green: 0.54947716, blue: 0.1281470656, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.9409626126, green: 0.7209432721, blue: 0.1315650344, alpha: 1)]
        let yellow = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.9409626126, green: 0.7209432721, blue: 0.1315650344, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.8931249976, green: 0.5340107679, blue: 0.08877573162, alpha: 1)]
        let green = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.3796315193, green: 0.7958304286, blue: 0.2592983842, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.2060100436, green: 0.6006633639, blue: 0.09944178909, alpha: 1)]
        let greenBlue = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.2761503458, green: 0.824685812, blue: 0.7065336704, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.6422213912, blue: 0.568986237, alpha: 1)]
        let kindaBlue = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.2494148612, green: 0.8105323911, blue: 0.8425348401, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.6073564887, blue: 0.7661359906, alpha: 1)]
        let skyBlue = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.3045541644, green: 0.6749247313, blue: 0.9517192245, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.008423916064, green: 0.4699558616, blue: 0.882807076, alpha: 1)]
        let blue = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.1774400771, green: 0.466574192, blue: 0.8732826114, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.00491155684, green: 0.287129879, blue: 0.7411141396, alpha: 1)]
        let bluePurple = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.4613699913, green: 0.3118675947, blue: 0.8906354308, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.3018293083, green: 0.1458326578, blue: 0.7334778905, alpha: 1)]
        let purple = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.7080290914, green: 0.3073516488, blue: 0.8653779626, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.5031493902, green: 0.1100070402, blue: 0.6790940762, alpha: 1)]
        let pink = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.9495453238, green: 0.4185881019, blue: 0.6859942079, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.8123683333, green: 0.1657164991, blue: 0.5003474355, alpha: 1)]
        
        let colorsTable: [Int: [UIColor]] = [0: red, 1: orangeRed, 2: orange, 3: yellow, 4: green, 5: greenBlue, 6: kindaBlue, 7: skyBlue, 8: blue, 9: bluePurple, 10: bluePurple, 11: purple, 12: pink]
        
        let randomColors = colorsTable.values.randomElement()
        
        return randomColors!
    }
    
    
    
  
    let deleteButton: UIButton = {
        let deleteButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:2,y:2,width:70,height:30))
        return deleteButton
    }()

    let listNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let listLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:2,y:50,width:70,height:30))
        listLabel.text = "Data entry on Second View"
        listLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
        listLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        listLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        listLabel.tag = 1
        return listLabel
    }()
    
    
    let iconImageView: UIImageView = {
         let imageView = UIImageView()
         imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Folder")
         imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
         return imageView
     }()
 

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

[Edit Button on Cells that doesn't disappear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsBMC.png)